# How can I simulate in rviz or gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to simulate many behaviors of wheeled mobile robot such as mapping or navigation.I have found that ROS have package like navigation and gmapping,how can I run this package in simulation environment?

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270808/how-can-i-simulate-in-rviz-or-gazebo/) by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 138 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your simulated robot needs odometry and laser data to create maps. Odometry typically comes from your gazebo controller plugin. I used a controller from the hector_gazebo_plugins package (see http://wiki.ros.org/hector_gazebo_plugins). To generate simulated laser scan data you can use e.g. the Hokuyo plugin (see http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins&cat=connect_ros#GPULaser).

If you do not have a simulated robot yet, you might want to start with an already existing robot model for Gazebo, like the TurtleBot simulator (http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator).
There are also tutorials around for using gmapping or amcl on the TurtleBot (see http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation). These tutorials should also work on a simulated TurtleBot.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) on 2017-09-15**:
thanks,I did it,that looks so cool.But now I want to Setup and Configuration of the Navigation Stack on a Robot([link text](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation))，I want to run navigation stack on turtlebot.is there any ways?What should I do to?  thank you !

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2017-09-18**:
I am glad to hear, that you got your simulation and gmapping up and running. The Gaitech EDU tutorials might help you to learn more about using the navigation stack on a TurtleBot: http://edu.gaitech.hk/turtlebot/map-navigation.html